# The content type 'application/json; charset=utf-8' was not the expected type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8' Error

Tags: javascript, xml, json, wcf, dynamics-crm-2011

I am getting error which is 'The content type 'application/json; charset=utf-8' was not the expected type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8' Error' while trying to add WCF service.

The Javascript Code:

```
var $jbis = jQuery.noConflict();

var LiveUrl = "http://" + window.location.hostname + "/ISV/CRM.QuoteCopyEntitiesService/";
var serverUrlOData = LiveUrl + "/QuoteCopyEntitiesService.svc";

var jsonParameters = window.JSON.stringify(parameters);

$jbis.support.cors = true;

var dataResult = null;

$jbis.ajax({ type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    datatype: "json",
    async: false,
    data: jsonParameters,
    url: serverUrlOData + functionName,
    beforeSend: function (XMLHttpRequest) {
        /*Specifying this header ensures that the results will be returned as JSON.*/
        XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
   }, success: function (data, textStatus, XmlHttpRequest) {
        if (data.d != null) {
            dataResult = data.d;
        } else {
            dataResult = data;
        }
    }, error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("WCF Hata" + errorThrown.toString() + " - " + textStatus.toString());
    }
});

return dataResult;
```

The Service Code:

```
public Guid CreateQuote(IOrganizationService service, Guid formId)
        {
            ColumnSet cols = new ColumnSet(true);
            Guid cloneId = Guid.Empty;
            Entity retrievedQuote = service.Retrieve("quote", formId, cols);

            Entity clone = Microsoft.Xrm.Client.EntityExtensions.Clone(retrievedQuote, false);
            clone.Attributes.Remove("quoteid");
            clone.Id = Guid.NewGuid();

            cloneId = service.Create(clone);

            return cloneId;
        }
```

The Interface

```
[WebGet(RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        [OperationContract]
        Guid CreateQuote(IOrganizationService service, Guid formId);
```

The Web.config in WCF

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
        <httpModules>
            <clear />
        </httpModules>
    </system.web>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <protocolMapping>
            <add scheme="http" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" />
        </protocolMapping>
        <bindings>
            <webHttpBinding>
                <binding name="webBinding" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" closeTimeout="00:10:00" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" bypassProxyOnLocal="true" useDefaultWebProxy="false">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
                </binding>
            </webHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <services>
            <service name="QuoteCopyEntitiesService" behaviorConfiguration="QuoteCopyEntitiesService.ServiceBehavior">
                <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="QuoteCopyEntitiesService.EndPointBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webBinding" contract="IQuoteCopyEntitiesService" />
            </service>
        </services>
        <behaviors>
            <endpointBehaviors>
                <behavior name="EndPointBehavior">
                    <enableWebScript />
                </behavior>
            </endpointBehaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="QuoteCopyEntitiesService.ServiceBehavior">
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
                    <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="6553600" />
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="false" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true /">
    </system.serviceModel>
    <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
        <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: well i mean ur trying to read a JSON output from what is clearly an XML file. to solve it, change either your request or the file so that the two align.

Comment: But how can I do it?

Comment: I'm sorry if my mild sarcasm didn't come through ... you are trying to access data in an XML file by using JSON, which is a lot like trying to ride a motorcycle by peddling. It isn't going to happen. What may help is instead getting familiar with jQuery's XML Parser => http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsexml/. You can retrieve the document without the JSON parameters, then parse it once retrieved to get the data in the tag that you need.

Comment: $jbis.ajax({ type: "POST",
        contentType: "text/xml; charset=utf-8",
        datatype: "xml",
        async: false,
        data: jsonParameters,
        url: serverUrlOData + functionName,
        beforeSend: function (XMLHttpRequest) {
            XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Accept", "text/xml");
       }, success: function (data, textStatus, XmlHttpRequest) {
            if (data.d != null) {
                dataResult = data.d;
            } else {
                dataResult = data;
            }
        }
    });  It doesn't work like that, I am new at js

Comment: i mean ... do you know what you're trying to retrieve with `data.d`? there are several disconnections that are transpiring here, i mean the entire JS structure you have is based on accessing JSON data, however you are accessing XML data. you need to rewrite your JS to work with XML (because things like `data.d` wont work). i know you want a quick fix, but it isnt.